# fetch data from php for canvas js

Tags: php, jquery, canvasjs

ok so the thing is i need to create charts and i found canvas js, which looks promising, problem is i have the website on php and i dont know how to give data to the charts from php to jquery to charts, basically how to feed it from mysqli database and php with jquery.

i didnt find any explanation on the main website and its chatbot want my number straight away so no use.

this is my 2nd question so if this is not the right question to ask without any code, i am sorry, ill take care of it in the future. but i dont have any code cause i dont know where to start. with php to fetch data. and feed it to the chart through jquery.

Comment: The question is a bit too broad and unspecific at the moment. But if you look at canvas js documentation, you can see that the format and structure it needs for the data. (it's just json), so all you need to do is to get what you need in PHP and encode it to json in the correct format. Break it up into smaller tasks and take one thing at the time, like getting the data from the db, structure it correctly, then encode it to json and last add it to canvas js. If you get stuck on something specific along the way, come back and we can help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code-Samples for rendering chart with data from datababse is readily available in [CanvasJS gallery section](https://canvasjs.com/php-charts/chart-data-from-database/). You can even download working sample from [download page](https://canvasjs.com/download-html5-charting-graphing-library/), which you can run in your local machine directly.
[image: CavnasJS Samples - Download Page]

If you still unable to make it work or facing issue, share the code with brief of the issue you are facing so that the community can help you!